# mysql detail query string, like wildcard

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, wildcard

Not sure how to title my question... lol.

Below is what i am needing.

---

Values in my database look like the following: test_example-1, test_example-2, test_example-TD-1

The values can vary in length, "test_example-" is just an example, some of the values will have varying names.

When i perform a query to grab all the values that look like this "test_example-" i get everything, because i am using the wild card value this way "test_example-%". However, i do not want the "test_example-TD-1" in the result. I only want the NON-TD values. So, how can i get all the "test_example-" without getting stuff that has more than just a single digit integer after the "-".

A value in the database will not have anymore than a single digit number (0-9) after the "-". So basically i need a query that searches for values that would look like this "test_example-[0-9]".

How can i do that? If this is confusing and needs clarification, please let me know. Thanks!

---

Here is the exact query that i am doing to ease some confusion:

```
SELECT MAC, NAME FROM HOST WHERE NAME LIKE (SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(NAME, LENGTH(NAME)-1), "%") FROM HOST WHERE MAC="some mac address");
```

---

Here is the working result ( thanks to swati ):

```
SELECT MAC, NAME FROM HOST WHERE NAME REGEXP CONCAT(LEFT(NAME, LENGTH(NAME)-1), "[0-9]+") AND MAC="some mac address";
```

Comment: added the query i am trying to use for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `value` REGEXP "test_example-[:digit:]+"
```

That should work for test_example-[0-9]. More on [Character Classes and REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

With your given query, it would be:

```
SELECT MAC, NAME FROM HOST WHERE NAME REGEXP CONCAT(LEFT(NAME, LENGTH(NAME)-1), "[0-9]+") AND MAC="some mac address"
```

Note there is an error in your posted query - you have two WHERE clauses.

Comment: added the query i am trying to use for clarification.

Comment: Is it the Mac address field that you're trying to make sure has digits only?

Comment: The extra where is not an error it is intended, because i select name and mac from host where ( the name associated with the mac address from host )

Comment: Use "AND" instead of WHERE again.

Comment: And "test_example-" will not always be the value. That particular part of the value can vary. I was just using "test_exmaple-" as an example. It could be "hullabaloo-", doesnt matter.

Comment: Is there any pattern to what it could be? Only letters? alpha numeric? You can use the other character classes appropriately to define what you need in there.

Comment: basically i have a table containing the columns mac and name. The only value that i am going to know when trying to make the query in my OP is the mac address. And there is no pattern. I am only wanting to select the mac and name that have a single digit after the "-". If it has anything that is not "0-9" after the "-" then i do not want that value.

Comment: You were right about the where statement. Here is the final query. Thanks for the help. SELECT MAC, NAME FROM HOST WHERE NAME REGEXP CONCAT(LEFT(NAME, LENGTH(NAME)-1), "[0-9]+") AND MAC="some mac address";

Comment: Np, i had to change the ":digit:" part to "0-9". The digit part was not working, but 0-9 is. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: It did not give an error, it would just not give me a result.

Comment: Hmm; not sure. I've posted your query as the answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: You have a good day too, i had already posted the query in my OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
where substring(field,locate('-',field)+1,1) in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')
```

Comment: That would work, yes, but i need it to not be specific to the TD case. As there are more than just -TD. So, i need something that would look for integers after the "-" and not just -TD.

Comment: @Hogan: i see that, i will try the reg expression answer and yours. See which one is best. Thanks

Comment: @prolink007 - interested to find out the results, have a hard time believing there exists a sql implementation where the regex would be faster.

Comment: Just noticed that your way is based on the length of the value being constant. This is not the case. The length of the "field" is variable. Probably should have used better examples, sorry about that.

Comment: @prolink007 so it is a digit after the first `-`?

Comment: Correct, and only one digit. There will never be multiple digits.

Comment: @prolink007 - but that is the last requirements change I will accept.

Comment: I added my exact query to the OP, if you want to take a look at it. Maybe that will help out a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a [regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), though I don't know how efficient it will be. You might want to do it in code rather then in sql. but still:

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `value` REGEXP "yourRegexp"
```

Just create any regexp that satisfies your needs.

Comment: added the query i am trying to use for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an underscore character as the wildcard for a single character.

```
"test_example-_"
```

Comment: The single character would have to be specifically 0-9 and not just a character though.

Comment: @prolink007: Perhaps I misunderstood. I thought all unwanted strings would have at least 2 characters, "TD", after the initial part.

Comment: No problem, i had a hard time wording what i needed. Most likely not your fault, =P

Comment: added the query i am trying to use for clarification.