# mysql query and regexp problem

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

A few months ago i asked the question below.

[My question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036207/mysql-detail-query-string-like-wildcard)

However, i have ran into a problem.

When i use this query:

```
SELECT MAC, NAME FROM DB.HOST WHERE NAME REGEXP (SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(NAME, LENGTH(NAME)-1), "[0-9]+") FROM DB.HOST WHERE MAC="some mac");
```

If the mac address is resolved to "example_224-06-55" and their is another element in the DB named "example_224-06-55-00" they will both show up as a result of this query. I only want "example_224-06-55" to show up as a result of that query.

The size of the name's will vary, the examples are just examples.

I am having a really hard time figuring this out, any help is greatly appreciated!

THE WORKING QUERY:

```
SELECT MAC, NAME FROM DB.HOST WHERE NAME REGEXP (SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(NAME, LENGTH(NAME)-1), "[0-9][[:>:]]") FROM DB.HOST WHERE MAC="some mac");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL supports a special *word boundary* pattern `[[:>:]]` to solve this.

```
SELECT MAC, NAME FROM DB.HOST 
WHERE NAME REGEXP (
 SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(NAME, LENGTH(NAME)-1), '[0-9]+[[:>:]]') 
 FROM DB.HOST 
 WHERE MAC='some mac'
);
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html, the word boundary patterns are documented near the bottom of the page.

ps: Use single-quotes for string literals in SQL.  Double-quotes are for delimited identifiers.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, that worked great! However, for it to work, i did have to remove the "+".

Answer (score 2):

Update your regular expression that exactly you want.

```
SELECT MAC, NAME FROM DB.HOST 
 WHERE NAME REGEXP 
  (SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(NAME, LENGTH(NAME)-1), "_[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+$") 
    FROM DB.HOST WHERE MAC="some mac");
```

Comment: It can be of a varrying length, that was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a pattern for strings ending with numbers like 'xxx-xx-xx' instead of `"[0-9]+"` you can use `"\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d"`

Comment: The size can be different every time. It might not always be only 7 digits, it might be 9 next time, or 5.

Comment: Then please clarify why the string "example_224-06-55-00" does not satisfy your requirements. Is it about the trailing zeroes ?

Comment: Because if the "some mac" is resolved to a name "example_224-06-55" and their exists another name in the DB "example_224-06-55-00" they will both show up. I only want "example_224-06-55" to show up.

Comment: Thanks, just didn't get what the exact problem was at once :)